# How to get rid of "nano not found" warnings, without installing nano?

Tags: debian, vim, nano

Installed Debian Stretch (9.3). Installed Vim and removed Nano. Vim is selected as the default editor.

Every time I run `crontab -e`, I get these warnings:

```
root@franklin:~# crontab -e
no crontab for root - using an empty one
/usr/bin/sensible-editor: 25: /usr/bin/sensible-editor: /bin/nano: not found
/usr/bin/sensible-editor: 28: /usr/bin/sensible-editor: nano: not found
/usr/bin/sensible-editor: 31: /usr/bin/sensible-editor: nano-tiny: not found
No modification made
```

I've tried reconfiguring the `sensible-utils` package, but it gives no input (indicating success with whatever it's doing), but the warnings still appear.

```
root@franklin:~# dpkg-reconfigure sensible-utils
root@franklin:~#
```

Although these warnings don't prevent me from doing anything, I find them quite annoying. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found my own answer and so I'm posting it here, in case it helps someone else.

In the root user's home directory, `/root`, there was a file alled `.selected_editor`, which still retained this content:

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/nano"
```

The content suggests that the command `select-editor` is used to select a new editor, but at any rate, I removed the file (being in a bad mood and feeling the urge to obliterate something) and was then given the option of selecting the editor again when running `crontab -e`, at which point I selected `vim.basic`, and all was fine after that. The new content of the file reflects that selection now:

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

Comment: Interesting. Conventionally, the environment variable to control what `visudo`, `git` (when prompting for a commit message to be edited), `mutt` and other tools will use is just `EDITOR` (for barebones/baseline scenarios), or `VISUAL` (when curses is available).

Comment: @Christopher, alternatives is system-wide, `~/.selected-editor` per-user.

Answer (score 7):

The generic Linux way to set the default editor is to set `VISUAL` shell variable to the desired editor. For example in `.bashrc` add line like this:

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vi
```

This will set every time you login in to the system `vi` as visual editor

Comment: This is Debian.  It has the `alternatives` and the `sensible-` mechanisms _as well_.

Comment: @JdeBP, did I mention in the answer "generic"?

Comment: This is not generic.  [This is Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#editors-and-pagers), and the question is about changing an existing setting in `sensible-editor` specifically.

Comment: Another possibility is to set the `EDITOR` environment variable which is what I do.

Answer (score 3):

Another neat trick is to do `update-alternatives` and pick your preferred editor. This not only gives you the privilege to pick one but also let you see what editors are on your system:

```
update-alternatives --config editor
```

Result:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Then simply type the number of your preferred editor and hit the return key.