# Why is neomutt defaulting to nano? It's not my default editor.

Tags: email, environment-variables, mutt

I'm setting up a brand new computer and one quirk that I can't figure out is that neomutt is using nano as its default editor. My default editor is vim. Why wouldn't neomutt respect that?

Comment: do you have `set editor` or `set visual` somewhere in the `(neo)?mutt` config?

Comment: How are you setting `vim` as your default editor?  what does your shell show with `echo $EDITOR`?

Comment: Sigh. I thought that it was set in `.bashrc` but it wasn't. Not sure why `edit whatever.txt` was defaulting to vim and neomutt to nano, but nothing was set explicitly.

Comment: There's a table of priorities here [1.3. Config Priority](https://neomutt.org/guide/configuration.html#1-3-%C2%A0config-priority); also iirc `$VISUAL` will take priority over `$EDITOR`

Comment: @steeldriver That's helpful. It's still kind of a mystery, as `$VISUAL` wasn't set either and per [the documentation](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference.html#3-71-%C2%A0editor) it should default to `vi`. So I still don't know where it was getting nano from.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410668/ .

Answer (score 3):

`neomutt` should follow the [table of priorities](https://neomutt.org/guide/configuration.html#1-3-%C2%A0config-priority) in their documentation to decide what editor to use.

You can set the editor explicitly by adding `export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"` to your `.bashrc`.

Alternatively, if you only want to set the editor for `neomutt`, you can add the following to `~/.neomuttrc`:

```
set editor="/usr/bin/vim"
```

Comment: And to add to that: The `export EDITOR=...` line should go into your shell profile (other programs might use it, too).

Comment: @dirkt let's see if it works for the OP first

Comment: Setting the editor explicitly in .bashrc worked to change the editor, but I'm still working on figuring out why it was defaulting to nano in the first place.