# what application owns the $EDITOR and/or $VISUAL variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Im tidying up my bash exports file and categorizing variables depending what environment they are belong to.

for example the `HISTIGNORE`, `PATH`, `PS1`, etc.. are on the "Bash Section"
and `MANPAGER` on the "Man Section"..

I'm just wondering how about $EDITOR and/or $VISUAL? I can't seem to find them on bash man page.

Comment: Might be useful reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/117549

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have misclassified `PATH` and both `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` belong with it.

The idea that these variables *belong* to particular applications is wrong.  They are standardized and usable by potentially *any* application that needs them.

- If *any* application wants to search a path for executable programs, it can use `PATH`.  (And indeed this is the case for any application that calls `execvp()`.)
- If *any* application wants to invoke a shell, it can use `SHELL` to find the program image file.
- If *any* application wants to invoke a line editor, it can use `EDITOR`.
- If *any* application wants to invoke a visual editor, it can use `VISUAL`.
- If *any* application wants to invoke a pager, it can use `PAGER`.
- If *any* application wants to know where the home directory is, it can use `HOME`.

And so on.

In contrast, `HISTIGNORE` and `PS1` do not even really need to be environment variables at all; and only the latter is even mentioned (albeit without explanation) in the standard.  One *can* set them as environment variables, in a session-leader process or in some other top-level parent, and rely upon environment inheritance to have them imported by shells.

But one can *instead* just set them as *shell* variables, in a script automatically executed by every shell (the specifics depending from the shell), and not export them into the environment.  For example:  I have my `~/.zshrc` set `PS1` and `RPROMPT` as *shell* variables, and they are *not* exported to be *environment* variables at all.

## Further reading

- ["Other environment variables"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).  *Base Definitions*.  Single UNIX Specification.  IEEE 1003.1.  2018.  The Open Group.
- [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html).  *System Interfaces*.  Single UNIX Specification.  IEEE 1003.1.  2018.  The Open Group.
- [VISUAL vs. EDITOR – what’s the difference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/)
- [What is the `editor` command in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/)
- [Command for the default in-terminal text editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316856/)
- [Which systems have 'pager' shortcut/alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5383/)
- [How to get rid of "nano not found" warnings, without installing nano?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410668/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). *[Unix editors and pagers](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-editors-and-pagers.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Thanks! this clarrify too much of my misunderstanding.. +1 for the resources too

Answer (score 1):

`man bash` mentions both the variables under `edit-and-execute-command`:

> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell
>    commands.  Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and `emacs` as the editor, in that order.

Other programs often use the variables, too.

Comment: `bash` may also switch command line editing mode depending on the values of these variables.